# How can I communicate back the result from a std::thread to the Gui main thread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

In order to learn about threading in Qt and C++ I am creating a small example program.
It has a Gui with a button and a text field:

[image]

When the user presses the Calculate button it calculates pi using a sum formula.
In order for the Gui to be responsive during this lengthy operation the calculation will be performed in a separate thread.

First I created a subclass of `QThread` that does the calculation in its `run()` method and emits the signal `void resultReady(double value);` when it is finished.
This signal I connected to the slot `void setResult(double value);` in my `Dialog` Gui class.
This approach works fine.

Now I want to do the same thing using std::thread. How do I do this?
I am having problems communicating the result back to the Gui. I tried this:

```
class StdThreadStrategy : public QObject {
public:
    void doTheWork() {
        double pi = pi_sum();
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [=] { dialog->setResult(pi); });
    }
    // This is called by Dialog when the user presses the Calculate button:
    void calculatePi(Dialog* dialog) {
        this->dialog = dialog;
        std::thread t(&StdThreadStrategy::doTheWork, this);
        thread = std::move(t);
    }
private:
    Dialog* dialog;
    std::thread thread;
};
```

A `StdThreadStrategy` object is constructed in the constructor of `Dialog`:

```
Dialog::Dialog() : QDialog() {
  // .. create gui code
  calculatePiStrategy = new StdThreadStrategy();
}

// this is the slot I want called from the other thread:
void Dialog::setResult(double value) {
  piLineEdit->setText(QString::number(value));
}

// Called by Calculate button:
void Dialog::calculate() {
  calculatePiStrategy->calculatePi(this);
}
```

I was hoping using `QTimer::singleShot` in the `doTheWork()` method would allow me to post to the event queue of the Gui from another thread.
Unfortunately I get the error message: `QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread`.

**How can I communicate back the result from a std::thread to the Gui main thread in Qt?**

Comment: How do you start your thread(s)?

Comment: @vahancho: I added some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `signal` to your instance of `StdThreadStrategy`, and connect that via an *explicitly deferred* connection to the handler living in the UI thread. That way, you can safely call the signal from any thread, Qt takes care of sending it where it should go.

Also don't forget to `join()` your thread in the destructor of `StdThreadStrategy`. You also need to be aware that recycling a single instance like that is going to end up in race conditions. Just go and try what happens when you click the button again before pi had been fully computed.

Comment: Thank you Ext3h for an elegant solution! Per your instructions I added connect(calculatePiStrategy, &StdThreadStrategy::valueCalculated, this, &Dialog::setResult, Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection); to the Dialog constructor and this worked fine. Clicking the button again before pi had been fully computed caused a crash on thread = std::move(t); so it seems that moving to running threads is not allowed.

Comment: @Andy it's not the move which isn't allowed, but the fact that you must `join()` the already running thread before you are allowed to forget it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general answer to this kind of design problems. I give you just some tips here to show that c++11 provides a higher level of abstraction that can ease the manipulation of thread lifetime.

In your main GUI thread, run the async task (here I use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) what gives you a std::future for further manipulation)

```
auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [=]() {
            // do some work
        });
```

Now, your UI is alive, run a Qtimer in the main thread with a callback that will check for the async procedure.

```
// callback content will be something like this
// checking via the future the state of the async task
if (fut.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(25)) !=
                           std::future_status::ready) {
   // not yet finished
   return;
}

// No do what you want with the result
auto res = fut.get();
// emit a signal to refresh the gui etc.
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a custom QEvent that carries the result from the worker thread to the thread your QObject lives in. See [QEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) and [QCoreApplication::postEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent)

Create your event class:

```cpp
class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    MyEvent(double result) : QEvent(QEvent::User), mResult(result) {
    }

    double result() {
        return mResult;
    }

private:
    double mResult;
};
```

Post the event to the event loop and override the event() function to catch it:

```cpp
class StdThreadStrategy : public QObject {
...
    void doTheWork() {
        double pi = pi_sum();
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new MyEvent(pi));
    }
...
    bool event(QEvent *event) override {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::User) {
            const auto result = static_cast<MyEvent*>(event)->result();
            dialog->setResult(result);
        }
        return QObject::event(event);
    }
...
}
```